# Am I tanning? If so, how can I stop?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In New Leaf, it appears that my character's skin is starting to darken due to the hot summer sun. Is there a way to prevent this? Or am I just imagining?

Comment: another great arqade question title. +1 to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Tan)

> ## Preventing a Tan
>
> To *prevent* a tan, go out with an umbrella, don't go out while it's
> daytime, or stay inside. Drastic measures include Time Travelling or
> staying off the game for long periods of time. Hats will not stop tans
> from appearing.
>
> ## Removing the Tan
>
> - Take precautions. When going outside on sunny days, the player should use an umbrella or anything that will block out sun completely.
> - Wait it off. Tans will fade after a while, and with some extra help it should be gone in no time.
> - Stay in a building or animal's house for about an hour. Turn the game off and save, time travel to the next day, and then repeat. Keep
>   doing that for a while and the player's tan should eventually start to
>   fade.

[Liquefy's FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/faqs/65246) on ACNL also has some additional info.

Comment: According to Liquefy's FAQ on GameFAQs, wearing items such as the Bug Mask, the Hero's Cap, the Batter's Helmet, etc. prevent a tan from developing, which contradicts the wiki's claim that "Hats will not stop tans from appearing." The wiki claims there are five different levels of tan, but the FAQ claims there are seven. These inconsistencies suggest further research is required.

Comment: The wiki is a general guide on all the AC though, and the stuff mentioned might hold true for previous games but not ACNL?

Comment: Be careful when time traveling. It has some annoying side effects like having weeds grow all over your town.

Comment: Helmets prevent tans for sure

Comment: @Ben Such as the Majora's Mask?

Comment: @Animal-Crosser probably. I'm wearing Samus' helmet and I never tan. And I've left the game idle standing outside for hours before without a tan